# Weird behaviour on Plone after migration

Tags: plone

After migrating from Plone 3.3.2 to 4.3.6, the result when accessing a forum item is simply:

```
<Products.Five.metaclass.ConversationView object at 0x7f24404e3a50>
```

There is no trace, error or log entry.

The buildout.cfg file used contains the following:

```
eggs =
    Plone
    Pillow
    archetypes.kss
    collective.captcha
    plone.app.caching
    plone.app.discussion
    plone.app.registry
    plone.app.kss
    plone.openid
    plone.registry
    Products.ATReferenceBrowserWidget
    Products.Clouseau
    Products.CMFNotification
    Products.CMFPlacefulWorkflow
    Products.DocFinderTab
    Products.kupu
    Products.NuPlone
    Products.Ploneboard
    Products.PloneboardNotify
    Products.PloneFormGen
    Products.ResourceRegistries
    Products.SimpleAttachment
    zope.app.container
    zope.app.cache
    zope.app.component
    zope.app.pagetemplate
    zope.app.publisher
    zope.copypastemove
    zope.dublincore
    zope.hookable
```

...

```
[versions]
buildout.sanitycheck = 1.0b1
Cheetah = 2.2.1
collective.recipe.backup = 2.20
Pillow = 2.6.1
plone.recipe.command = 1.1
plone.recipe.unifiedinstaller = 4.3.2
Products.DocFinderTab = 1.0.5
setuptools = 7.0
zc.buildout = 2.2.5
ZopeSkel = 2.21.2
zopeskel.dexterity = 1.5.4.1
zopeskel.diazotheme = 1.1
Products.Ploneboard = 3.4
```

Any ideas of what may be causing this?

Thank in advance,

Comment: "forum item" means a Ploneboard forum, right?

Comment: looks like the view is not called - instead the view class is returned. i'd look up which view is defined as default view for your forum items and check the associated template/class.

Comment: @keul - yes, a Ploneboard forum

Comment: @fRiSi - There is no "Default view method" field for the "/Plone/portal_types/Discussion Item" item. Is there other field I should look for?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

@joao the type "Discussion Item" is shipped with plone by default. it's not releated to ploneboard.

according to [the type definition](https://github.com/collective/Products.Ploneboard/blob/master/src/Products/Ploneboard/profiles/default/types/PloneboardConversation.xml)
the conversation type should use `conversation_browserview` as deault view.
try to call the url http://yoursite/path/to/forum/conversation/@@conversation_browserview
if this works without problems, you need to update `PloneboardConversation` in portal_types to use this view as default view.
If you still get the error try the latest code from master and file a ticket if it still persists.

Answer (score 2):

It seems a problem in the default view of the object.
Check in ZMI -> portal_types -> your content type